# Moving around EU as a UK EU citizen

Tags: eu, spain, tax-treaties

I am a remote worker currently living in the UK, homeowner, with my own ltd company, working for UK clients.  I use things like upwork and freelancer sites to carry out my work, invoice etc and pay taxes to HMRC in the UK.

I am planning to move next year and rent a place in Spain for probably more than the 90 days I keep hearing about, maybe 6 months, after renting out my place (all declared to UK above board etc) in the UK.

What I'm struggling to understand and get others views on how they do it, to long term rent somewhere in Spain, with the view I may come back etc for work - but simply rent and not need to pay double tax?  I possibly will need insurances, a bank account and to buy a car etc, but I am not earning income or providing services within Spain - basically I'm just doing it to stay in warmer climes!

Does anyone have any UK EU to EU experiences they can share?  I'm not trying to dodge taxes, local NI or responsibilities but I find it hard to see how remote workers get by?

Comment: One way to avoid double taxation could be to create a company *in Spain*.

Comment: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7081/can-an-eu-citizen-move-to-another-eu-country-to-work-remotely-at-a-job-not-in-th (especially the answer by Peter Taylor) might be of interest.

Comment: I can probably help on some specific questions, but to put your question in 'official' terminology, your question is about 'an EEA national exercising treaty rights'. That will help your internet research.

Comment: And a thing to watch out for is that different countries have different tax years, and if it makes a difference whether you were in a country more or less than six months then this is likely in the tax year. If you stay Jan to July in Spain, you were 7 months in Spain, but three months away from UK in one year and four months in another.